# Pear installation in Windows XAMPP PHP 8.1.10

Tags: php, xampp, pear

As I was following the instructions on how to install PEAR from the official [manual,][1] and got this error:

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'phar://go-pear.phar/index.php' (include_path='C:\xampp_latest\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp_latest\php\go-pear.phar:1284 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp_latest\php\go-pear.phar on line 1284`

I tried looking for other solutions and found [this][2]. However, I still couldn't install pear and still get this error:

`PHP Fatal error:  Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no longer supported in C:\xampp_latest\php\go-pear.php on line 1182`.

I tried the installation via webbased and command line, but got the same error.

Just another update..
I went ahead and searched even more and got to this:
[link](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate_curly_braces_array_access)
So I tried to change the curly braces into square brackets from different files as suggested from the errors, and at the end, I got this error:

```
    PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function error_handler(), 4 passed and exactly 5 expected in C:\xampp_latest\php\pear\pearcmd.php:446
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: error_handler(8192, 'trim(): Passing...', 'C:\\xampp_latest...', 152)
#1 C:\xampp_latest\php\pear\PEAR\XMLParser.php(152): trim(NULL)
#2 C:\xampp_latest\php\pear\PEAR\XMLParser.php(166): PEAR_XMLParser->postProcess(NULL, 'options')
#3 [internal function]: PEAR_XMLParser->endHandler(Object(XMLParser), 'options')
#4 C:\xampp_latest\php\pear\PEAR\XMLParser.php(102): xml_parse(Object(XMLParser), '<commands versi...')
#5 C:\xampp_latest\php\pear\PEAR\Command.php(247): PEAR_XMLParser->parse('<commands versi...')
#6 C:\xampp_latest\php\pear\PEAR\Command.php(302): PEAR_Command::registerCommands()
#7 C:\xampp_latest\php\pear\pearcmd.php(54): PEAR_Command::getCommands()
#8 {main}
  thrown in C:\xampp_latest\php\pear\pearcmd.php on line 446

  [1]: https://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php
  [2]: https://www.ivankristianto.com/install-or-update-pear-on-xampp-for-windows/
```

Comment: I also tried to download Pear for manual installation through the website https://pear.php.net/package/PEAR/download/1.10.13
But the download buttons don't seem to work. :(

Answer (score 6):

Basically the PEAR provided with xampp is not updated to run under PHP 8.x. and is facing to several deprecated and removed features in PHP 8.0 that cause the PHP Fatal errors.

**1) Accessing characters issue** 
The first problem is with [strings access by the zero-based offset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr)  when access using curly brackets `{}` was removed and only square brackets `[]` can be used.

> Accessing characters within string literals using the {} syntax has been deprecated in PHP 7.4. This has been removed in PHP 8.0.

Compare original code

```
$arg{0}
```

with fixed code:

```
$arg[0]
```

**Solution:** 
Search all files in your `xampp/php/pear` folder with regular expression `\{(\$[a-zA-Z0-9\+]*)\}` and replace it with `[$1]` 
*IMPORTANT*: review each occurrence not to alter regex expressions in the scripts!!!



**2) Uncaught ArgumentCountError  issue**
The second problem is with php function [set_error_handler](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) where was [removed last param in PHP 8.0.0](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php#refsect1-function.set-error-handler-changelog). 
The call back function expects *five params* however it gets only *four params* and therefore the call fails with `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function error_handler(), 4 passed and exactly 5 expected`.

**Solution:** 
Search for the `set_error_handler(` calls and find the refereed call back function `error_handler` and make the last param optional. 
In my case it was in script `xampp\php\pear\pearcmd.php`  and the function definition was on line 446:

Compare original function definition:

```
function error_handler($errno, $errmsg, $file, $line, $vars)
```

with applied fix:

```
function error_handler($errno, $errmsg, $file, $line, $vars = null)
```

Note: I found that "bug" has been already reported on the [Apache Friends Support Forum](https://community.apachefriends.org/viewtopic.php?t=81268&p=274260) already back in September 2021..



**3) Undefined function each() issue** 
The third problem is is with removed PHP function [each()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.each.php) that is throwing `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function each()`.

> This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.2.0, and REMOVED as of PHP 8.0.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged.

**Solution** 
Search for all occurrences of  `each(` (use the space to eliminate function 'foreach' in the result set) and review and update it with function `foreach` with proper params used in each file. \

An example of `while` syntax

```
while (list($i, $arg) = each($args)) {
```

can be replaced with

```
foreach ($args as $i => $arg) {
```

An example of `list` syntax

```
list(,$first) = each($lines);
```

can be replaced with

```
foreach($lines as $first){}
```

There are some other cases used in `If - else` statements that can be replaced by `emtpy($args)` followed by `foreach($args as $opt_arg){}` to build the variable $opt_arg.

An example of `If - else` syntax

```
if (!strlen($opt_arg) && !(list(, $opt_arg) = each($args))) {
```

can be replaced with

```
if (!strlen($opt_arg) && !empty($args)) {
       foreach($args as $opt_arg){}
```

And PEAR is finally working with XAMPP Version: 8.2.0

```
C:\xampp\php>pear help version
PEAR Version: 1.10.1
PHP Version: 8.2.0
Zend Engine Version: 4.2.0
Running on: Windows NT D5KGFJF 10.0 build 19045 (Windows 10) AMD64
```

Comment: this answer deserves way more than the upvote i'm able to give, so.. thank you!